# How to parse part of script code in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, file, oop

I have a task to create an UI to run methods from scripts. 
I made a method that shows the names of Methods from Script, and on the UI there is a checkbox next to them. 
I have a problem that when I click on the checkbox, I do not know to invite only a pieces of code of  this method.

```
        private void GetAllDSCConfigurationName(string psFile, DSCTreeViewItemFolder item)
    {
        var file = new DSCTreeViewItemScipt() { Script = psFile };
        item.AddChild(file);

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(psFile))
            {

                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("Configuration"))
                    {
                        file.AddChild(new DSCTreeViewItemConfiguration() { ConfigurationName = line });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Example of Script:
########
Configuration LogOff
{
    Script LogOffUsers
    {
    }
}
####
Configuration StopServices
{
    param([bool] $Client)
}
}

And I only want if Checked 'Configuration LogOff' only call that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the same if statement:

```
if(line.StartsWith("Configuration") && line.Contains("LogOff"))
{
     // do your stuff
     break; // cause you don't need to look for other methods
}
```

If you have a name of your method from UI you can pass it to Contains method.
Also you can improve a bit your code:

```
string allLines = sr.ReadToEnd();
string configurations = allLines.Split("Configuration");
string methodToCall = configurations.FirstOrDefault(conf => conf.Contains("LogOff")); // or you can pass name of your method from parameter
```